# How to retrieve the HTML of a page from CommonCrawl?

Tags: common-crawl

Assuming I have:

- the link of the CC*.warc file (and the file itself, if it helps);
- offset; and
- length

How can I get the HTML content of that page?

Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [warcio](https://pypi.org/project/warcio/) it would be simply:

```
warcio extract --payload <file.warc.gz> <offset>
```

Alternatively, fetch the WARC record using the HTTP range request and then extract the payload at offset 0:

```
curl -s -r331727487-$((331727487+6613-1)) \
   https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2020-40/segments/1600400203096.42/warc/CC-MAIN-20200922031902-20200922061902-00310.warc.gz \
   >warc_temp.warc.gz
warcio extract --payload warc_temp.warc.gz 0
```

The range starts at offset and ends at offset+length-1. See also [getting WARC file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307663/common-crawl-getting-warc-file/46315949)

Answer (score 0):

The below command worked for me.

warcio extract --payload CC-MAIN-20230928130936-20230928160936-00336.warc.gz 988155426 > nutsaboutmoney_from_warcio.html

The html file can then be read by a browser.

This was run in a virtual environment using python 3.11.6.
warcio had been installed in the virtual environment with: pip instal warcio